# Wondering what the difference is between passive and active in these two examples

Tags: passive-voice, transitivity, middle-voice

His trial was / is adjourned until April.
His trial adjourned until April.

The program is canceled.
The program canceled.

Answer (score 1):

The first two are both correct, because 'adjourned' can be considered an action. Both would be used in English conversation.

The second one, the 'is' is needed as 'cancelled' is not an action.